# How relationship between the Euler beta function and the strong nuclear force can be mathmatically be proved?

Tags: string-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, strong-force, special-functions

I'm Korean highschool student and was writing a report about Euler beta function and string theory. And I can know find that Euler beta function is similar with the strong nuclear force equation. But I can't find the mathematical proof anywhere. Please explain me simply.

Comment: To be honest I think a high school student writing a report connected with string theory is a bad idea.  It's a very complex theory and even understanding the [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) from a mathematical perspective alone would be a leap for most high school students.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking of the [Veneziano formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veneziano_amplitude). It was a suggestive guess, so there is  no proof.  It led to the [dual resonance model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_resonance_model). You are not going to understand this motivation unless you have a good grasp of quantum mechanics.

Comment: um, is it ture that strong nuclear force's equation is similar with Eular beta funcion? i just want to write that beta function's appearance is similar with strong nuclear force on my report

Comment: The strong force is what gives rise to the scattering that is approximated by Veneziano's formula.  There is no simple formula for the force.  The full theory of the strong force,  Quantum Chromodynamics, does not make use of any of Veneziono's ideas.

Comment: so you mean that there is no simple formula for the force, and strong force is what only gives rise to the scattering that is approximated by Veneziano. and it is hard to understand and write on my report by level of korean highschool student right?

Comment: Yes! That is a good summary.